# Magento 2: not able to get order details in observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order

I am not able to get order details in observer using **sales_order_save_before** event:-

Path: - /app/code/Company/Mymodule/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_delete_after">
        <observer name="Mymodule" instance="Company\Mymodule\Observer\Onafterdelete"/>
    </event>
    <event name="sales_order_save_before">
        <observer name="Mymodule" instance="Company\Mymodule\Observer\Onbeforesaveorder"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Path:- /app/code/Company/Mymodule/Observer/Onbeforesaveorder.php

```
class Onbeforesaveorder implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_resource;

    /**
    * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
    */
   protected $_logger;  

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }  

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    $orderObj = $observer->getOrder();
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    if($order->getId()){
        $this->_logger->debug($order->getEntityId()." observer1111");
    }

    if ($orderObj->getId()){
        $this->_logger->debug($orderObj->getEntityId()." observer22222");
    }

    $this->_logger->debug("observer3333");// event is fired because I am getting this message in my log file.
    return $this;
  }
}
```

I am trying two way to get order ID in my code but both way is not working.

Please let me know if I am missing any thing or doing wrong as event is fired but not able to get order details in observer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `checkout_submit_all_after` event. The event which you are using will not have order data as order will not be created by then.

Answer (score 0):

Write a below code to Company\Mymodule\etc\events.xml

```
sales_model_service_quote_submit_before
```

You can get order id by below code

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($observer->getOrder()->getIncrementId());
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Not working

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: I have did the same

Comment: Check my updated answer, you will get order id.

Comment: I am able to get Increment Id but not order id, How to get order is here?

Comment: Check it with getId():

Comment: Not working I think when event is fired ID is not assigned to order

Comment: Which order information you want to get?

Comment: I need order id for some process for my ERP plugin as described in document

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
<?php
namespace modulename\frontname\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class OrderPlace implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {

        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        foreach ($orderids as $orderid) {
            $order = $this->order->load($orderid);
        }

        $storeId = $order->getStoreId();
        $oldStatus = $order->getOrigData('status');
        $newStatus = $order->getData('status');\

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Company\Mymodule\etc\events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
    <observer name="getorderinfo" instance="Company\Mymodule\Observer\Onbeforesaveorder"/>
</event>
```

**In observer file,**

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Company\Mymodule\Model\Transaction;

class Onbeforesaveorder extends AbstractObserver
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $address = $observer->getEvent()->getAddress();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CompanySaveCommitAfter implements ObserverInterface
{  
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $company = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
         } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        return  $exception->getMessage();
    }
    return $this;
   }
}
```